# C++ mpir : How to initialize mpz_t array?

Tags: c++

**Source:**

```
//$ DO DECLARATION
#define VEC_MAX_SIZE 600000
mpz_t Vec[ VEC_MAX_SIZE ];

//$ DO INITIALIZATION
mpz_array_init( Vec[ 0 ], VEC_MAX_SIZE, 2000 ); // Stack overflow error - 3rd param
```

**Problem:**

The problem is that I don't know how to properly initialize an mpz_t array, which in this case is Vec. The error is stack overflow. I think it is caused by the 3rd parameter. Here is the protype/definition of mpz_array_init:

```
#define mpz_array_init __gmpz_array_init
__GMP_DECLSPEC void mpz_array_init __GMP_PROTO ((mpz_ptr, mp_size_t, mp_size_t));
```

**Error:**

```
Unhandled exception at 0x008e8377 in TestMPIR.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow.
```

**Note:**

I am using mpir 3.1.1 on Windows 7 64 Bit.

This one from mpir's example works fine:

```
mpz_t Vec[ 20000 ];
mpz_array_init( Vec[ 0 ], 20000, 512 );
```

**ANSWER:**

Thanks to @Zeta for his/her awesome answer.
Correct me if I am wrong. I just want to post this here so other newbies can learn from it.

```
#define MAX_VEC_SIZE 600000
```

**malloc method (should be for C style I guess):**

```
mpz_t *Vec;

if( ( Vec = ( mpz_t *)::malloc( sizeof( mpz_t ) * MAX_VEC_SIZE ) ) == 0 ) {
    ::perror( "Out of memory" );
    return false;
}

//> Initialize Vec loop ( ... )

::free( Vec );
```

**C++ style?**

```
mpz_t *VecEx = new mpz_t[ MAX_VEC_SIZE ];

//> Initialize VecEx loop ( ... )

delete [ ] VecEx;
```

This answer is based on @Zeta's answer (the accepted answer).

Comment: can you try this mpz_array_init( Vec, VEC_MAX_SIZE, sizeof(mpz_t) )

Comment: Done, and it gives the same error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's simply not enough space on the stack for such a large vector ("stack overflow"). You have to allocate it dynamically:

```
mpz_t * Vec = malloc(VEC_MAX_SIZE * sizeof(mpz_t));
```

`Vec` is roughly 6MiB in size. The stack isn't big enough for such objects. Note that GMP also provides a [C++ interface](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/gmp/gmp_72.html).

Comment: Error: error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'void *' to 'mpz_t (*)'
1>        Conversion from 'void*' to pointer to non-'void' requires an explicit cast

Comment: FWIW, I would promote [Boost.MultiPrecision](http://www.boost.org/libs/multiprecision/) as the preferred C++ front-end for GMP.

Comment: Resolved error C2440: mpz_t *Vec = ( mpz_t *)::malloc( sizeof( mpz_t ) * VEC_MAX_SIZE );

Comment: @CLearner: I used `malloc` without typecast since I thought you were using `C` when I answered the question. The return of `malloc` needs to be cast correctly in C++. Even more, you should use `mpz_t * Vec = new mpz_t[VEC_MAX_SIZE]` in C++ instead.

Comment: @Zeta thank you. Its funny because I was going to post a question about Vec = new mpz_t vs malloc